# Nagios Check that Simulates Web Full Rendering Time

Tags: monitoring, nagios, performance-monitoring

Does anyone know of a Nagios plugin or cli program that can simulate the load time of a webpage as it would be in a browser.

For example the resulting total load time of something like [Pingdom's Full Page Test](http://tools.pingdom.com/) or the timeline you get from firebug.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Selenium is the defacto standard for full-browser-render testing, so take a look at the [check_selenium plugin](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Websites,-Forms-and-Transactions/check_selenium/details)

Comment: One major plus for this choice is that the website link for the plugin links to a blog with SF flair on it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Could you script a browser? You might be able to use AppleScript to `tell` Safari to load the page and time it, if you are running on a Mac.

I don't know if this is close enough to a 'real' browser for your purposes, but another option is to use [HTMLUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/), which is a Java library that is used for things such as User Acceptance Testing, Screen Scraping, and so-on. You could use the same library to time how long it takes for a page to load, but obviously this is a Java engine rather than a real browser so the performance may not be representative of what any particular user experiences. You may also not want to run Java-based Nagios scripts.

Answer (score 1):

[Nagios Exchange](http://exchange.nagios.org/) has a simple PHP-based plugin which checks the load time of a webpage and reports if it takes longer than a specificed period of time.  It is called "[Check Website Speed](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Uncategorized/Check-Website-Speed/details)"

Comment: But that does not include images and scripts

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Selenium-RC and [this](http://code.google.com/p/selenium-profiler/)? IANAWD/IANAWP, so I cannot say for sure.  I have just heard a lot of good things and Selenium before.

EDIT: Yeah, I'm the kind of idiot that did not read the first answer, but proceeded to recycle it. Apologies everybody.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Nagios check script that starts a web browser. Selenium or the iMacros Firefox/Chrome addons will work fine for that purpose. Both are free and open-source.

Example: Start iMacros for Firefox [via the command line](http://wiki.imacros.net/iMacros_for_Firefox#Command_Line_Support) and run a small macro like

```
VERSION BUILD=7110203 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=http://serverfault.com/
TAG POS=1 TYPE=H1 ATTR=ID:h-top-questions
```

=> This will give you the exact page load time in Firefox or [Chrome](http://wiki.imacros.net/iMacros_for_Chrome#Command_Line_Support). Plus, you can use the same setup for transaction monitoring.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe worth a look: [phantomjs-nagios](https://github.com/hggh/phantomjs-nagios): "Render an complete Webpage headless and test load time with nagios".

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find a list with some website speed tests:
https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Websites,-Forms-and-Transactions